# How to output the regression prediction from each tree in a Random Forest in Python scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm new to scikit-learn and random forest regression and was wondering if there is an easy way to get the predictions from **every tree** in a random forest in addition to the combined prediction.

Basically I want to have what in R you can do with the `predict.all = True` option.

```py
# Import the model we are using
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
# Instantiate model with 1000 decision trees
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 1337)
# Train the model on training data
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels)
# Use the forest's predict method on the test data
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
print(len(predictions)) #6565 which is the number of observations my test set has.
```

I want to have every single prediction of every single tree, not only the mean of them for each prediction.

Is it possible to do it in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
import numpy as np
predictions_all = np.array([tree.predict(X) for tree in rf.estimators_])
print(predictions_all.shape) #(1000, 6565) 1000 rows: one for every Tree, 6565 columns, one for every target
```

This uses the `estimators_`-attribute (see [Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.RandomForestRegressor.html)), which is a list of all the trained [DecisionTreeRegressors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html). We can then call the predict method on each one of them and save that to an array.